# PostgreSQL cross join Table

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Initial Situation:**

**Table1:**

```
Table1  s1_a    s2_b    s3_c    s_key
Table1  a1      b1      c1       1
Table1  a2      b2      c2       2
Table1  a3      b3      c3       3
Table1  a4      b4      c4       4
```

**Table2:**

```
Table2  d1_q    d2_w    d3_e    d_key
Table2  q1      w1      e1      1
Table2  q2      w2      e2      2
Table2  q3      w3      e3      3
```

How can I get this result: common columns are s_key & d_key -> key

```
Extract View    s1_a    s2_b    s3_c    key     d1_q     d2_w     d3_e
Extract View    a1      b1      c1      1
Extract View    a2      b2      c2      2
Extract View    a3      b3      c3      3
Extract View    a4      b4      c4      4
Extract View                            1       q1       w1       e1
Extract View                            2       q2       w2       e2
Extract View                            3       q3       w3       e3
```

Answer (score 0):

No reason for a cross join here. Just an old fashioned UNION ALL will do the trick:

```
SELECT s1_a, s2_b, s3_c, s_key, NULL as d1_q, NULL as d2_w, NULL as d3_e FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, d_key, d1_q, d2_w, d3_e FROM Table2
```